# How can I create a child node by selecting a parent node using jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

It is my first project using jQuery.

I have created parent nodes using jstree. When the user clicks on any of the parent nodes, I want a child node to be created in that respective parent node.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#container').on('click', function(){

        var newNode = { data: "Child1" };
        var parentNode = $('#container').jstree('get_node', event.target.id); 
        $("#container").jstree(true).create_node(parentNode, newNode, "last");
        
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The container click events will not give you the selected node. The jsTree API has specific events for this. You should be using the `select_node.jstree` event to identify node selections.

```
$("#container").bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var newNode = { data: "Child1" };
    $("#container").jstree(true).create_node(data.node.id, newNode, "last");
});
```